# Within a field template, how can I print the value of another field from the same node?

Tags: theming, 8, entities

I have an email field that I would like to present on the node as a name that links to the email address. As such, I am trying to edit the email field template to embed the name from a text field. However, I'm having difficulty figuring out how to access the content of this text field. I've gotten as far as figuring out that `twig(_context['element']['#object'])` will give me some info about the node object, but I cannot figure out how to access the field values. Am I even in the right ballpark for accessing this data?

Comment: Use preprocess function to get to the node object from the field(i think it's either getParent() or getEntity() method) and either put the whole node into the variables or just the field you want to access...or just the value of course.

Comment: As of drupal 8.4+ the following debug string will show properties of the node in a field html twig file:

`{{ dump(_context['element']['#object']) }}`

Note that twig debugging should be enabled in the sitewide services.yml file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the node object that you have found in the field template.

You can access the field values like this:

```
{{ element['#object'].field_field1.value }}
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks! Do you have any good resources for this aspect of theming in D8?